# Flex: How to put a object to the datagrid from a file?

Tags: apache-flex

First, I have this function:

```
private var file:File = new File;

public function openBrowse():void{

  file.browseForOpen("Objekt auswählen");

}
```

but how can I put the object to a datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:DataGrid id                    ="rackData"
             dataProvider          ="{scacheDB}"
             verticalScrollPolicy  ="on"
             horizontalScrollPolicy="on"
             itemClick             ="rackDataClick(event);"
             includeIn             ="default">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Rack ID"
                           dataField ="rackBarcode"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Rack Name"
                           dataField ="rackName"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Max Rows"
                           dataField ="maxRow"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Max Columns"
                           dataField ="maxCol"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Location"
                           dataField ="location"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

In this case scacheDB is an array collection that I read in from a file.  I did read it in as XML, then converted it to an array collection with the field names listed above.  The datagrid is dynamic, so any time I change scacheDB, the datagrid will be updated, at least in this case.  For pure AS3 you will have to create an item renderer to handle the update, but the logic is the same.

```
var rackData : DataGrid = new DataGrid;
rackData.dataProvider = scacheDB;
```

Hope this helps.